# MPAndroidChart- How to add cells inside grids like Graph sheet?

Tags: android, graph, grid, mpandroidchart, cells

How to create a cells inside grids in MpAndroidchart library?
Sample Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fNd2.png

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to change the background of the chart. Since the chart is transparent by default, if you manage to get hold of the background picture like in your image, you could use the drawable and change the chart's background and tinker around with it.

You could use this for your chart:
In your XML : `android:background="....."` or `setBackgroundResource(.....)` in your java.