# How Can I Draw Cells Inside MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

How can I draw cells inside LineChart

I am able to display lines dynamically, but didn't find how to draw inner cells.

I have followed these examples

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3751

[MPAndroidChart- How to add cells inside grids like Graph sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401946/mpandroidchart-how-to-add-cells-inside-grids-like-graph-sheet)

any suggestion will be appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

> in layout.xml file

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
     android:id="@+id/chart"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

> in Activity.java

```
LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
.
.
.
  XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)
xAxis.setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

.
.
.
 YAxis yAxisRight = lineChart.getAxisRight();
        yAxisRight.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        yAxisRight.setDrawGridLines(true);
yAxisRight.setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
.
.
.
 YAxis yAxisLeft = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxisLeft.setDrawGridLines(true);
yAxisLeft.setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Comment: Hi @Aniruddh this will draw x and y axis and change its color , i want to draw small rectangle inside x and y axis

Comment: yes, setDrawGridLines(true);  it will draw grid Lines in both x and y axis, in which color you have specified but if you want to small rectangle then you can set fixed interval between values you are providing to show in graph.

Comment: that's the only way is possible in mpChartLib to show the grid Lines.

Comment: the grid lines are showing with custom color, the problem is small rectangle inside x and y

Comment: if you want small rectangle between x and y Axis then set a fixed small value  interval between values in x and y axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can override AxisRenderer.drawGridLine and change grid line width.

```
private class CustomXAxisRenderer(
    viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler,
    xAxis: XAxis,
    trans: Transformer
) : XAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans) {

    override fun drawGridLine(c: Canvas?, x: Float, y: Float, gridLinePath: Path?) {
        mGridPaint.strokeWidth = (if (x.toInt() % 5 == 0) 2 else 1).toFloat()
        super.drawGridLine(c, x, y, gridLinePath)
    }

}
```

...

```
chart.setXAxisRenderer(CustomXAxisRenderer(mViewPortHandler, mXAxis, mLeftAxisTransformer))
```

Comment: what is mLeftAxisTransformer

Comment: if i change it it is changing , xAxis value not drawing small rect inside graph